# Most Efficient Way to Calculate the Product of All Items in a List?

Tags: list-manipulation

Say that I have a list of returns on a financial asset over time and want to know the total compounded return. To get the answer, I need to add 1 to each return and then calculate the product of all of them. So, I'm looking for a function like `Total`, except that it computes the product. The `Product` function works, but seems clumsy and slower than my alternatives (at first, I was having trouble getting `Product` to work, so I wrote a few of my own functions). Here are the alternatives:

```
listProduct[x_List] := Exp[Total[Log[x]]];
listProduct2[x_List] := Last[FoldList[Times, 1, x]];
listProduct3[x_List] := Fold[Times, 1, x];
listProduct4[x_List] := Product[x[[i]], {i, 1, Length[x]}];
```

Those are in the order that I thought of them. A couple of surprising things: The first seems to be the fastest by quite a lot (though none are super slow). The slowest is the last one using `Product`, which I thought would be highly optimized and fast.

Here are my tests:

```
s = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.05, 0.1], 10^6];
listProduct[1 + s] - 1; // AbsoluteTiming
listProduct2[1 + s] - 1; // AbsoluteTiming
listProduct3[1 + s] - 1; // AbsoluteTiming
listProduct4[1 + s] - 1; // AbsoluteTiming
```

which produces these results:

```
{0.0312000, Null} {1.4820026, Null} {1.4040025, Null} {1.8252032, Null}
```

So, the question is: Is there a faster way, and am I missing some built-in function that would do this better? I won't be using lists this long, but I may be doing a lot of lists if I can get the rest of my idea implemented.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `Times`. Use it as `Times@@list`, or keeping in line with your functions,

```
listProduct[x_List] := Times @@ x
```

Comment: Excellent. I knew there must be a more elegant way to do it. I'm still new to MMA and haven't quite wrapped my head around Apply (until now), so this didn't even occur to me. This is still slower than the first method, but I like the elegance of it. Thanks!

Comment: @TimMayes That's correct, but if your list is a list of integers, then this will be much faster than any of your solutions (perhaps, the fastest of all). Try it with `s = RandomInteger[10^3, 10^6];`. Note: your solutions 2,3,4 are extremely slow with this, so I would just accept it and skip the waiting and test only with your first method and mine.

Comment: @Tim just get into the habit of thinking about `Apply` replacing heads. So if you have `List[x1,x2,x3,...]` if you replace the head `List` with `Times` you now have `Times[x1,x2,x3,...]`

Comment: Very interesting. It is several times faster with integers. That is more inline with what I would expect. Unfortunately, I'm not using integers, but I'll try to remember this.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, thanks that helps. MMA is so different from what I'm used to programming in, but I'm slowly learning.

Comment: @TimMayes by way of another example, before `Total` was added to Mma people used to do `Plus@@{x1,x2,x3,...}` which gives `Plus[x1,x2,x3,...]`

Comment: What does `_list` do?

Answer (score 21):

`Apply[Times, list]` is the canonical Mathematica way to represent applying an operation (such as multiplication) to the elements of a list.

Since your question asked about the *most efficient* way to calculate the product, I will point you to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294640/is-there-a-fast-product-operation-for-packedarrays) on Stack Overflow which discussed this issue at length.

The upshot is

- If the elements of the list are all machine precision integers, reals or complexes stored in a [PackedArray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775543/379673) *and* the result will be small enough to be representable as a machine precision number as well, then a specialized function created with `Compile` is going to be the fastest.

  If you have a C compiler and Mathematica 8, you can also automatically compile all the way to C code as:

  ```
  compiledlistproduct = Compile[{{l, _Real, 1}}, 
      Module[{tot = 1.}, Do[tot *= x, {x, l}]; tot], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
  ```

  A temporary DLL is created and linked back into Mathematica at run-time. The result will be essentially as fast as dedicated Mathematica functions like [Total](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Total.html).
- If the result might be too large to be represented as a machine number, but you are happy with an approximate real/complex-valued result (even if the underlying objects are exact integers), then `Exp[Total[Log[N[list]]]]` or some variant on it (such as a custom `Compiled` function doing something similar) is the next thing to try.

  - The `Log` operation keeps numbers in range of faster machine arithmetic for longer.
  - The N ([documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html)) in `N[list]` turns exact integers into fast approximate machine reals (so you don't end up with relatively slow exact quantities like `Log[2]`).
- Otherwise go with `Apply[Times, list]`.

See the Stack Overflow post linked above for more details, timings, and links to more related questions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was baffled by why my method of using `Log`would be so fast since it is using several operations. Your second point gets to that.

Comment: Actually `Exp[Total[Log[N[list]]]]` should be used (using `N[list]` instead of `list`) to turn a machine integer array (for which Log will give slower exact results like `Log[2]`) into a fast machine real array (like `Log[2.0]`, which evaluates straight to a machine real). I will a correction to my answer for that.

Comment: Talking about compiling, this also sounds like something that could be tackled with a CUDA routine if your need for speed is so great as to warrant the additional effort to implement this. Speculative: Maybe one could even use something like `ImageMultiply` or `CUDAImageMultiply` together with clever partitioning as a starting point?

Answer (score 15):

I asked essentially [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5294640/618728) on StackOverflow when I was dissatisfied with the speed of `Times @@ list` on a packed array.  Please read the answers to that question for some really good information.  Ultimately I came away with this as the fastest sign-aware list product function for *Mathematica* 7:

```
listProd = (-1)^(-1 /. Rule @@@ Tally@Sign@# /. -1 -> 0) * Exp@Total@Log@Abs@# &;
```

Timings:

```
list = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1*^7];

Times @@ list // Timing
listProd @ list // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.858, -9.16325884049*10^-4340292}
>
> {0.078, -9.1632601*10^-4340292}
> ```

As you can see a certain loss of precision occurs, but computation is more than an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: I think it should be `1 /. Rule ...`

Comment: @R.M actually that isn't correct either (I believe).  This was written *assuming* negative numbers in the list, and it fails in the case where there aren't any.  I shall fix this later today if I have time.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't entirely sure either — just noticed that it fails if there aren't any negative numbers, whereas using 1 gave the result in all my test cases.

Comment: @R.M function updated; please see if it appears correct to you now.

Comment: Wow, this is the kind of thing that I marvel at. Beautiful, but I'll need to upgrade my MMA skills before I'd be comfortable using it even knowing that it works.

Comment: @Tim as you can see from the comments above it *didn't* work.  I do think it is fixed now.  Read the original question and answers on StackOverflow for an understanding of the principles behind this.  Basically it is in two parts:  `Exp@Total@Log@Abs@#` finds the absolute product of the list; this part seems pretty solid as it is directly mathematical;  `(-1)^(-1 /. Rule @@@ Tally@Sign@# /. -1 -> 0)` finds the sign of the product of the list by raising `-1` to the number of negative numbers in the list; this is more tricky but the fastest code I could find.

Comment: Perhaps, for complete generality, `Exp[I Total@Arg@lst]`?