# Why it seems that there is no counterpart function as to multiplication, to `Total` as to addition?

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language, language-design

`Times` and `Plus` have the same grammar, and so do `Product` and `Sum`. So is there a function doing multiplication that has the same grammar as `Total` does then?

If yes, what is it? If no, why?

---

Now I learn from @AntonAntonov that there is less need to design a `ListProduct` function. So this indicates that multiplication and addition cannot be treated on the same footing.

---

About "duplicate": I think not. Because my question is not aimed at finding how, but at why.

About "off-topic": I think it constructive to make some of the design "philosophy" behind clearer to facilitate deeper understanding.

Comment: Related [prior MSE thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/most-efficient-way-to-calculate-the-product-of-all-items-in-a-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most Efficient Way to Calculate the Product of All Items in a List?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/most-efficient-way-to-calculate-the-product-of-all-items-in-a-list)

Comment: How about `prod = Apply[Times]`?  `prod[{1,2,3,4}]` --> 24.

Comment: Also `Fold[Times]`, which can be faster than `Apply[Times]` on packed arrays.  And `Tr[#, Times] &`. although `Tr` is slightly slower than `Apply`.

Comment: Um, "If yes, what is it?" seems "aimed at finding how." And, it seems to me, that many if not most users who ask "why?" are really interested in "how?", judging by which answer they accept.  Of course, (1) you're not most users, just one, and (2) I'm not voting to close anyway.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*In addition to the [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171642/34008)...*

I designed and implemented `Total` 17 years ago. Its first version was named `ListSum`. The primary reason for `ListSum`'s implementation was to encapsulate the functionalities dealing with error accumulation while summing a list of numbers. (A well known phenomena in, say, numerical solvers for ODE's.)

Of course, I also considered `ListProduct`, having analogous functionality. But there was not really a strong reason or use case for it.

(During the final design phase Stephen Wolfram renamed `ListSum` to `Total`.)

---

@tomd

> My memory of things is that before Total, Tr@lst was considered faster than Plus@@lst if lst was a packed array, an observation Ted Ersek attributes to Rob Knapp

Rob Knapp was supervising my work on the `Total` project.

Comment: Thanks for the historical context!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks, I thought it might be of interest...

Comment: @AntonAntonov I think it interesting too.

Answer (score 16):

`Total` is different from `Plus@@` because it uses [tricks to minimize round-off error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). It is thus a useful addition to the toolkit. `Times@@` doesn't suffer from the problem, so no similar function is needed.

Comment: Could you please give a concrete example demonstrating that, concerning to round-off errors, `Total` and `Plus@@` are different?

Comment: I prefer to state it as `Apply[Plus]` rather than the syntax `Plus@@`, because `Apply[Plus]` is actually a function now that we're in the brave new curried world!

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ See the documentation of [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html), section Examples->Options->Method.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Yes, there it is. But I find that it is `Total` that suffers from round-off error if not used with the specified method, rather than `Plus@@` or `Apply[Plus]`.

Comment: My memory of things is that before Total, `Tr@lst` was considered faster than `Plus@@lst` if lst was a packed array, an observation [Ted Ersek](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_P-Z_31.html) attributes to [Rob Knapp](http://members.wolfram.com/rknapp/)

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Related: [(103771)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103771), [(145019)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145019)

Comment: `Times@@` doesn't suffer from the problem [citation needed]. Also `Times@@` unpacks packed arrays.