# What is the correct syntax for performing a summation using numbers from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

I have the following lines of code:

```
l={1,2,3,4,5}
n=5

Summation= n l
Total[Summation]
```

I would like to perform the same thing above, but in a more elegant fashion using  `Sum[f,{i,imax}]`.  Is there another way to do this type of operation or is a brute force approach better? (The example shown is relatively simplistic so there isn't much "brute force" going on)

Comment: Do you mean 4th syntax of `Sum` in the document? `Sum[n i, {i, l}]`. BTW why do you think `Total` isn't elegant?

Comment: `Total[n l]` or `n Total[l]` or `Plus @@ (n l)` or `Sum` or probably even more options. To my taste, `Total` solutions are by far the most readable.

Comment: `Sum` is a bit artificial when values of `i` are explicitly listed items. It makes most sense for ranges...

Comment: Before `Total`, taking the trace of a vector (with `Tr`) was considered faster than `Plus@@vector` if the vector is a packed array.  As related [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171643/106), `Total` was developed by [Anton Antonov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34008/anton-antonov) under the supervision of [Rob Knapp](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/391/).  Ted Ersek has some interesting things to say on this topic [here](http://verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_P-Z_31.html)

Comment: See also [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171642/106) by [John Doty](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27989/john-doty) ('Total is different from Plus@@ because it uses tricks to minimize round-off error')

Comment: As is well know the sum of the first n integers is: $1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$