# Pick with Unitize vs Pick with Clip vs Compiled Select speed - anything faster?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering, compile

Given a large list of $n$ dimensional sublists where each sublist has integer elements I am trying to find the quickest way of finding all sublists that satisfy some constraint on their elements.

A typical constraint would be that a sublist sums to zero.

I have tried three ways - Pick with Unitize, Pick with Clip and compiling Select.

They all seem to have similar timings. The two Pick methods are somewhat faster for $n<6$ but compiling Select is faster for larger $n$.

Does anyone have a faster way of doing this? Especially when $n \ge6$?

```
(* n = 3 case *)

arr = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, {10000000, 3}];

constraint = #[[1]] + #[[2]] + #[[3]] == 0 &;
compile = 
  With[{criteria = constraint}, 
   Compile[{{input, _Integer, 2}}, Select[input, criteria], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]];

try1 = Pick[arr, 
     Unitize[#[[All, 1]] + #[[All, 2]] + #[[All, 3]] &@arr], 0]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First

try2 = compile[arr]; // RepeatedTiming // First

try3 = Pick[arr, 
     1 - 
      Clip[#[[All, 1]] + #[[All, 2]] + #[[All, 3]] &@arr, {0, 0}, {1, 
        1}], 1]; // RepeatedTiming // First

try1 == try2 == try3

(*
0.200528

0.379881

0.222603

True
*)
```

and

```
(* n = 9 case *)

arr2 = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, {10000000, 9}];

constraint = #[[1]] + #[[2]] + #[[3]] + #[[4]] + #[[5]] + #[[6]] + \
#[[7]] + #[[8]] + #[[9]] == 0 &;
compile = 
  With[{criteria = constraint}, 
   Compile[{{input, _Integer, 2}}, Select[input, criteria], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]];

try1 = Pick[arr2, 
     Unitize[#[[All, 1]] + #[[All, 2]] + #[[All, 3]] + #[[All, 
           4]] + #[[All, 5]] + #[[All, 6]] + #[[All, 7]] + #[[All, 
           8]] + #[[All, 9]] &@arr2], 0]; // RepeatedTiming // First

try2 = compile[arr2]; // RepeatedTiming // First

try3 = Pick[arr2, 
     1 - 
      Clip[#[[All, 1]] + #[[All, 2]] + #[[All, 3]] + #[[All, 
            4]] + #[[All, 5]] + #[[All, 6]] + #[[All, 7]] + #[[All, 
            8]] + #[[All, 9]] &@arr2, {0, 0}, {1, 1}], 1]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First

try1 == try2 == try3

(*
0.59877

0.446898

0.615144

True
*)
```

I am not sure of the etiquette on here in regard to extending the question and have received some great responses in the comments so far.

But as a matter of interest - instead of the summing to zero constraint - what would be a fast method of constraining the first  $n-1$ elements to be in ascending order?

i.e $ element[[1]] \le element[[2]] \le \dots element[[n-1]]$ in a sublist?

Comment: you can also try `Pick[arr, Total[arr, {2}], 0]`

Comment: `Pick[arr, arr.Table[1, Length[arr[[1]]]], 0]`

Comment: Before I anoint you both as code Jedis - can you give some insight as to why your methods are so much faster? I thought I was being moderately clever (well not clever in regard to just compiling Select LOL).

Comment: @chyanog you could cut that down further and remove the Length by doing `arr . (1 & /@ arr[[1]])` . Also might be worth checking ConstantArray vs Table, 
e . g `arr.ConstantArray[1, n]`

Comment: It seems the fastest by a hairs breadth is @chyanog answer. I get 0.0639 seconds for the n = 9 case.

Comment: `Total` was developed by [Anton Antonov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34008/anton-antonov) under the supervision of Rob Knapp. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171643/106) for an interesting post by AA. Before the development of `Total`, a trick was to use `Tr` (now considered slow). See the entry for `Tr` in [Clever little programs](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_P-Z_31.html) by [Ted Ersek](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_P-Z_31.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another implementation for selecting rows that sum to 0. It is designed to parallelize well and to avoid `Pick`.

```
n = 9;
arr2 = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, {10000000, n}];

threadCount = "ParallelThreadNumber" /. ("ParallelOptions" /. SystemOptions["ParallelOptions"]);
jobptr = 1 + Ceiling[(Length[arr2]) Subdivide[0., 1., threadCount]];

cf = Block[{input, i},
   With[{code = Sum[Compile`GetElement[input, i, j], {j, 1, n}] == 0},
    Compile[{{input, _Integer, 2}, {begin, _Integer}, {end, _Integer}},
     Block[{bag},
      bag = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]];
      Do[If[code, Internal`StuffBag[bag, i]], {i, begin, end - 1}];
      Internal`BagPart[bag, All]
      ],
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True,
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
    ]
   ];

result0 = Pick[arr2, Total[arr2, {2}], 0]; // RepeatedTiming // First
result1 = Pick[arr2, arr2.ConstantArray[1, n], 0]; // RepeatedTiming // First
result2 = arr2[[Join @@ cf[arr2, Most[jobptr], Rest[jobptr]]]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First

result0 == result1 == result2
```

> 0.279332
>
> 0.105336
>
> 0.0365174
>
> True

And here are some ideas for the extended question (picking rows that are ordered up to the penultimate element):

```
cg = With[{m = n - 1},
   Compile[{{input, _Integer, 2}, {begin, _Integer}, {end, _Integer}},
    Block[{b, c, x, y, bag},
     bag = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]];
     Do[
      b = True;
      c = 1;
      x = Compile`GetElement[input, i, 1];
      While[b && c < m,
       c++;
       y = Compile`GetElement[input, i, c];
       b = x <= y;
       x = y;
       ];
      If[b, Internal`StuffBag[bag, i]],
      {i, begin, end - 1}];
     Internal`BagPart[bag, All]
     ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];

A = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -1., Band[{2, 1}] -> 1.}, {n, n - 2}];
one = ConstantArray[1, n - 2];


result0 = Select[arr2, OrderedQ[Most[#]] &]; // RepeatedTiming // First
result1 = Pick[arr2, UnitStep[arr2 . A] . one, n - 2]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
result2 = arr2[[Join @@ cg[arr2, Most[jobptr], Rest[jobptr]]]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First

result0 == result1 == result2
```

> 10.6702
>
> 0.812736
>
> 0.0381827
>
> True

The approach for `result1` is to use a `SparseArray` `A` to apply the differences in each row. Then we apply `UnitStep` and sum the resulting entries to count the number of nonnegative entries (which correspond to an monotonically increasing pair of entries in the original matrix).

For `result2`, we again use the parallelized `CompiledFunction` `cg`. The `While` loop terminates early if it finds a pair of consecutive entries that is not monotonically increasing. `` Internal`Bag `` (along with `` Internal`StuffBag `` and `` Internal`BagPart ``) is an undocumented container type that allows efficient appending of elements (it's probably just using a C++ `std::vector` and its `push_back` routine as backend).

Comment: What can I say but fantastic answer. This part of my coding was my bottleneck from a speed perspective - it no longer isn't. Sadly for me the bottleneck is now something Mathematica has no control over. But I have gone from requiring several hours to five minutes or so (though I have jobs that still take a day or so but were previously going to take weeks) - with your recommendations plus some things I was doing in other areas of my code. Thank you very much Henrik.

Comment: I am pleased to hear that! Good luck for your project!