# Switched linear systems

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise

I'm curious whether it is possible to solve *switched linear systems* within the framework of `NDSolve`. For example a system of linear ode's like
$$x'(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} A_1 x(t),& \text{if} \,\,   x_1x_2\leq 0 \\ A_2 x(t), & \text{if} \,\, x_1x_2>0 \end{array}\right.$$

where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are two constant matrices with appropriate size (namely $A_1,A_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$) and $x(t) = \left(x_1(t),x_2(t)\right)^\top$.

I tried `WhenEvent` but received an error message saying

> "Warning: the rule !(*SuperscriptBox[\"x\", \"[Prime]\",
>   MultilineFunction->None][t] -> A1 . x[t]) will not directly set the 
>   state because the left-hand side is not a list of state variables."

Here is the code

```
A1 = {{0, -1}, {2, 0}};
A2 = {{0, -2}, {1, 0}};
x[t_] = {x1[t], x2[t]}

NDSolve[{x'[t] == A2.x[t], x1[0] == 6, x2[0] == 3, 
WhenEvent[x1[t] x2[t] <= 0, x'[t] -> A1.x[t]]}, {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 
100}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```

Comment: I wonder if it might work with the rhs expressed using `Piecewise`?

Comment: Indeed, if memory serves, `NDSolve[]` will set up the `WhenEvent[]` objects on your behalf if you use `Piecewise[]`. Still, it is useful to know how to adapt `WhenEvent[]` in case the automatic method fails.

Comment: Tried this: system = x'[t] == 
  Piecewise[{{A1.x[t], x1[t] x2[t] < 0}, {A2.x[t], x1[t] x2[t] > 0}}]; NDSolve[{system, x1[t] == 3, x2[0] == 2}, {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 10}]. I got the error: "Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function 
within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both 
values and derivatives of the functions"

Comment: Why are the initial conditions for both `x1` and `x2` scalars and not vectors? Try using `Indexed[]` if you want to refer to a vector-valued function componentwise, just like in your inequality conditions.

Comment: Like that? system = x'[t] == 
  Piecewise[{{A1.x[t], 
     Indexed[x, 1][t] Indexed[x, 2][t] < 0}, {A2.x[t], 
     Indexed[x, 1][t] Indexed[x, 2][t] > 0}}]; NDSolve[{system, Indexed[x, 1][0] == 3, 
  Indexed[x, 2][0] == 2}, {Indexed[x, 1], Indexed[x, 2]}, {t, 0, 10}]. Now I get the response "x appears with no arguments." But I can't see why this error message is generated

Comment: It doesn't seem that defining `x[t_] = {x1[t], x2[t]}` is enough for Mathematica to know the relationship between `x[t]` and `{x1[t],x2[t]}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise) in the vector form of the ODE, the only tricky part is how to create the condition. Here are two possibilities:

```
pm1 = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};

sol1 = NDSolveValue[
    {
    x'[t] == Piecewise[{{A2.x[t], x[t].pm1.x[t]>0}}, A1.x[t]],
    x[0] == {6, 3}
    },
    x,
    {t, 0, 100}
];

sol2 = NDSolveValue[
    {
    x'[t] == Piecewise[{{A2.x[t], Indexed[x[t], 1] Indexed[x[t], 2] > 0}}, A1.x[t]],
    x[0] == {6, 3}
    },
    x,
    {t, 0, 100}
];
```

Visualizations:

```
Plot[
    {Indexed[sol1[t],1], Indexed[sol1[t], 2]},
    {t,0,100},
    PlotRange->All
]
```

[image]

```
Plot[
    {Indexed[sol2[t],1], Indexed[sol2[t], 2]},
    {t,0,100},
    PlotRange->All
]
```

[image]

Comment: this approach works bueno under version 10.2. nice idea with the quadratic form. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Like the error message says, I believe `WhenEvent` needs to change a state variable, not its (highest) derivative.  Here's an approach that sets `A` as a `DiscreteVariable` that can be changed when needed.

```
listProduct[x_List] := Times @@ x;

A1 = {{0, -1}, {2, 0}};
A2 = {{0, -2}, {1, 0}};

sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == A[t].x[t], x[0] == {6, 3}, A[0] == A2,
  WhenEvent[listProduct[x[t]] <= 0, A[t] -> A1],
  WhenEvent[listProduct[x[t]] > 0, A[t] -> A2]}, {x, A}, {t, 0, 100},
  DiscreteVariables -> {A}][[1]];

Plot[Sign[listProduct[x[t] /. sol]], {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`listProduct` is by rm -rf from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1353/6358).

Comment: What version of mathematica do you use? I tried your code with version 10.2 and I can only integrate till t = 4 without waiting forever

Comment: v11.3 -- did you try a fresh kernel?

Comment: jep, tried that but unfortunately doesn't change anything…

Comment: Yeah, my colleague's v10.3 has the same problem.  Bug?