# Efficient primorial memoization?

Tags: files-and-directories, prime-numbers, memoization

Thinking on this [recent question asking to create an primorial list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/278112/10397), led me to think

**How could we exploit something similar to memoization for primorial?**

Maybe something that stored only the largest pre-computed list `primorial[m]`, and evaluated to `Take[primorial[m],n]` for $n<m$ and updated the definitions of `primorial` for $n>m$ only computing the new elements, without duplicating efforts.

**Furthermore, how to save that definition to file to easily recover pre-computed results?**

Comment: I have provided a solution, but I think there must be better performance approaches suitable for large arguments. Probably using File Streams?

Answer (score 3):

Using the usual recursive memoizaton scheme is not practical when evaluating for large numbers, as one easily reach the recursion and memory limits. Also, storing each solution for all integers duplicates information.

```
primorialm[1]= {1,2};
primorialm[n_Integer]:= primorialm[n] = Append[ primorialm[n-1], Last[primorialm[n-1]]*Prime[n]]
```

A better strategy would be to have a definition for only two cases:

1. A larger or equal arguments has been already computed, [`Take`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Take.html) a subset of that.
2. A smaller arguments is pre-computed start from there and complete the remaining terms.

now...

```
primorialAux = <| "n"->1,"list"-> {1,2}|>

ClearAll[primorial];
primorial[n_Integer?(# <= primorialAux["n"]&)] := Take[ primorialAux["list"], n+1 ]
primorial[n_Integer?(# > primorialAux["n"]&)] := CompoundExpression[
    primorialAux = <|
        "n"->n,
        "list"-> Join[
            primorialAux["list"],
            Rest@FoldList[Times, Last@primorialAux["list"], Prime[Range[primorialAux["n"]+1,n]]]
        ]
    |>,
    primorialAux["list"]
]
```

Now we can compute and save primorial like this

```
AbsoluteTiming[primorial[20000];]
(* {0.202288,Null} *)

DumpSave["primorialAux.mx", {primorialAux,primorial}];

Exit[]

Get["primorialAux.mx"]

AbsoluteTiming[primorial[10^4];]
(* {0.000189,Null} *)
```