# How to plot a function efficiently without having to recalculate

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, parallelization

I have to make a lot of graphs for two different functions Nzzp (which can be computed quickly without problem) and NzzG which requires three numerical integrations in a row so I'm using paralleltable so it creates a table with all the values I need and then use it to plot my function. The problem is, now I have to plot (NzzG - Nzzp) so I named a function as M=(NzzG - Nzzp) and tried to plot it but it is taking me a lot of time since it has to Re-calculate NzzG again. Is there any way to make this plot in a more efficient way?

This is Nzzp

```
Nzz2P[a_, b_, c_] := 
  1/3 (64 c^3 + 4 a^2 Sqrt[a^2 + 4 c^2] - 32 c^2 Sqrt[a^2 + 4 c^2] + 
     4 b^2 Sqrt[b^2 + 4 c^2] - 32 c^2 Sqrt[b^2 + 4 c^2] - 
     4 a^2 Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 4 c^2] - 4 b^2 Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 4 c^2] + 
     32 c^2 Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 4 c^2] - 
     48 a b c ArcTan[(a b)/(2 c Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 4 c^2])] - 
     24 a c^2 Log[2] - 48 b c^2 Log[2] - 24 (a + 2 b) c^2 Log[c] - 
     6 a^2 b Log[a^2 + 4 c^2] + 24 b c^2 Log[a^2 + 4 c^2] - 
     3 a b^2 Log[b^2 + 4 c^2] + 12 a c^2 Log[b^2 + 4 c^2] - 
     12 a c^2 Log[-a + Sqrt[a^2 + 4 c^2]] + 
     36 a c^2 Log[a + Sqrt[a^2 + 4 c^2]] + 
     48 b c^2 Log[b + Sqrt[b^2 + 4 c^2]] - 
     3 a b^2 Log[-a + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 4 c^2]] + 
     12 a c^2 Log[-a + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 4 c^2]] + 
     9 a b^2 Log[a + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 4 c^2]] - 
     36 a c^2 Log[a + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 4 c^2]] + 
     12 a^2 b Log[b + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 4 c^2]] - 
     48 b c^2 Log[b + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 + 4 c^2]]);
Nzz1P[a_, b_] := 
  4/3 (a^3 - a^2 Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] + b^2 (b - Sqrt[a^2 + b^2])) + 
   2 a b (-2 a Log[a/(b + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2])] + 
      b Log[1 + (2 a (a + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]))/b^2]);
NzzP[a_, b_, c_] := 
  1/(4 π (2 a) (2 b) (2 c)) (Nzz1P[2 a, 2 b] - 
     Nzz2P[2 a, 2 b, c]);
```

This is NzzG

```
F1[r_, r1_, φ_, φ0_, L_] := ( 
  r r1 (EllipticF[φ/2, -((4 r r1)/(L^2 + (r - r1)^2))] - 
     EllipticF[(φ - φ0)/
      2, -((4 r r1)/(L^2 + (r - r1)^2))]))/Sqrt[L^2 + (r - r1)^2];
NzzG[a_, b_, φ0_, L_] := 
 2/(π φ0 (b ^2 - a^2) L )
   NIntegrate[
   F1[r, r1, φ, φ0, 0] - 
    F1[r, r1, φ, φ0, L], {r, a, b}, {r1, a, r, 
    b}, {φ, 0, φ0}, MinRecursion -> 9, 
   MaxRecursion -> 40, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 100000}]
```

This is how I plot NzzG, first I make the table

```
a4 = 49.9;
b4 = 50;
NzzGvsLDat = 
  ParallelTable[{L, NzzG[a4, b4, π/180, L], 
    NzzG[a4, b4, 2 π/180, L], NzzG[a4, b4, 3 π/180, L], 
    NzzG[a4, b4, 4 π/180, L], NzzG[a4, b4, 5 π/180, L], 
    NzzG[a4, b4, 6 π/180, L], NzzG[a4, b4, 7 π/180, L], 
    NzzG[a4, b4, 8 π/180, L], NzzG[a4, b4, 9 π/180, L]}, {L, 
    1, 100, 2}];
```

Then I plot NzzG as

```
ListPlot[{{#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ NzzGvsLDat, {#[[1]], #[[3]]} & /@ 
   NzzGvsLDat, {#[[1]], #[[4]]} & /@ NzzGvsLDat, {#[[1]], #[[5]]} & /@
    NzzGvsLDat, {#[[1]], #[[6]]} & /@ NzzGvsLDat, {#[[1]], #[[7]]} & /@
    NzzGvsLDat, {#[[1]], #[[8]]} & /@ NzzGvsLDat, {#[[1]], #[[9]]} & /@
    NzzGvsLDat, {#[[1]], #[[10]]} & /@ NzzGvsLDat}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}, {Red, Dotted}, {Blue, Thick, 
    Dashing[{0.022, 0.01, 0.022, 0.015}]}, {Darker[Green], Thick, 
    Dashing[{0.01, 0.02, 0.02}]} , {Orange, Thick, Dashed} , {Magenta,
     Thick, Dotted}, {LightGray}, {Yellow}, {Purple, Thick, Dashed}}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

My attempt so make NzzG-Nzzp was:

```
M[b_, φ0_, L_] := 
  NzzG[49900, 50000, φ0, L] - NzzP[100, b, L];
Plot[{M[2  0.44 10^3, π/180, L  10^3], 
  M[2  0.87 10^3, 2 π/180, L  10^3], 
  M[2  1.31 10^3, 3 π/180, L  10^3], 
  M[2  1.75 10^3, 4 π/180, L  10^3], 
  M[2  2.2 10^3, 5 π/180, L  10^3], 
  M[2  2.6 10^3, 6 π/180, L  10^3], 
  M[2  3.1 10^3, 7 π/180, L  10^3], 
  M[2  3.5 10^3, 8 π/180, L  10^3], 
  M[2  4 10^3, 9 π/180, L  10^3]}, {L, 1, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}, {Red, Dotted}, {Blue, Thick, 
    Dashing[{0.022, 0.01, 0.022, 0.015}]}, {Darker[Green], Thick, 
    Dashing[{0.01, 0.02, 0.02}]} , {Orange, Thick, Dashed} , {Magenta,
     Thick, Dotted}, {LightGray}, {Yellow}, {Purple, Thick, Dashed}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 0.12}}, Frame -> True]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: CReate a function that approximates NzzG using "Interpolation"

Comment: Maybe use some [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)? [Here's a tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html) on how to do it in Mathematica.

Comment: There are so may options on what could be done, depending on what is acceptable (interpolation OK?) the memory that would take to cover the domain of interest, etc. You could combine Memoization as pointed out by Roman and `FunctionInterpolation` by Daniel in a way that the range of the interpolation gets expanded automatically if evaluated outside the previous domain. Something similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/278151/10397).